# Em uma matriz Z de elementos (i,j) como atribuir o valor 1 quando i=j? (software R)

Tags: r, loop, matriz, programação-funcional

Através da seguinte condição:

```
ifelse(??, 1, Z/(1+1))
```

O que colocar no lugar de "??" para que o R entenda que quando i=j na matriz Z, quero que se atribua o valor 1?

Comment: Por i=j você quer dizer o índice i = o índice j? Se for, a resposta do Daniel com `diag` é a mais adequada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não vejo uma forma de resolução simples a partir da sua pergunta. Mas proponho duas formas de resolução:

Atribuir o valor desejado à diagonal, de forma direta.

```
a <- matrix(rep(0,100), nrow = 10)
diag(a) <- 1
```

Analisar a posição para atribuir o valor.

```
a <- matrix(rep(0,100), nrow = 10)
for(i in 1:dim(a)[1]){
  for(j in 1:dim(a)[2]){
    if(i == j){
      a[i,j] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```