# Substituir valor em matriz (R)

Tags: r, matriz

Preciso substituir o valor que aparece na diagonal principal da minha matriz por outro, como proceder?

Comment: Um único valor da diagonal principal? Dê uma olhada na documentação da função `diag`. Seria legal apresentar a estrutura do seus dados para reprodução.

Comment: Isso, Rafael. É que eu realizei uma operação na matriz, mas essa operação não vale pra diagonal. Aí quero substituir por 1 (que era o valor anterior da diagonal, antes da operação).

Comment: Será que algum comando replace ou ifelse funcionaria?

Comment: salva o valor da diagonal em um objeto, faz a operação e depois substitui. minha ideia é algo do tipo: `valor <- diag(M)` --> `realizar a operação` --> `diag(M) <- valor`

Comment: Não entendi sua ideia Rafael. Poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: você tem sua matriz M, armazena os valores da diagonal em um objeto `valor <- diag(M)`, depois você realiza a operação necessária na matriz. Como você mesmo disse, os valores da diagonal vão alterar, depois você retorna com os valores originais `diag(M) <- valor`

Comment: E como eu insiro esse valor na matriz? isso que não consegui entender ainda

Comment: Então, o comando `diag(M) <- valor` vai inserir o valor na matriz. Eu vou colocar como resposta uns comandos para exemplificar

Comment: Rafael, deu certo. Muito obrigada!

Comment: Eu não tinha pedido novamente a matriz, por isso não tinha visto mudanças. Obrigada mesmo!

Comment: @LetDC esta pergunta você já fez em outro tópico. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213452/em-uma-matriz-z-de-elementos-i-j-como-atribuir-o-valor-1-quando-i-j-software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
M <- matrix(rpois(25, lambda = 4), ncol = 5)
M
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    4    3    4    3    6
[2,]    3    2    6    1    6
[3,]    3    4    6    4    1
[4,]    9    3    3    4    4
[5,]    3    5    6    3    8

valor <- diag(M)
valor
[1] 4 2 6 4 8

M <- (M**M)*10
M
           [,1]  [,2]   [,3] [,4]      [,5]
[1,]       2560   270   2560  270    466560
[2,]        270    40 466560   10    466560
[3,]        270  2560 466560 2560        10
[4,] 3874204890   270    270 2560      2560
[5,]        270 31250 466560  270 167772160

diag(M) <- valor
M
           [,1]  [,2]   [,3] [,4]   [,5]
[1,]          4   270   2560  270 466560
[2,]        270     2 466560   10 466560
[3,]        270  2560      6 2560     10
[4,] 3874204890   270    270    4   2560
[5,]        270 31250 466560  270      8
```